# Conditional expectation, exponential distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-probability

I have 2 exponential random-variables.
$T_1\sim\exp(\lambda_1)$ and $T_2\sim \exp(\lambda_2)$.

I want to find $E[T_1|T_1<T_2]$ with integration, however I am not able to set up the proper integral.

First I have to find this probability:

$$P(T_1<T_2)=\int_{0}^\infty\left[\int_{0}^{t_2}\lambda_1e^{-\lambda_1t_1} dt_1\right]\lambda_2e^{-\lambda_2t_2} dt_2=\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}, \tag{1}$$

But then I need to find:

$P(T_1 \le t_1 |T_1<T_2)$ (2), which I must differentiate to get:

$f(T_1=t_1|T_1<T_2)$ (3), which I then can integrate to get the desired expectation, like this:

$$E[T_1|T_1<T_2]=\int_{0}^\infty t_1*f(T_1=t_1|T_1<T_2) dt_1 \tag{4}$$

However, finding (2) and (3) is difficult:

I know that:
$P(T_1 \le t_1 |T_1<T_2)=\frac{P(T_1<t_1 \cap (T_1<T_2))}{P(T_1<T_2)}(5)$, and the denominator I have from (1), but how do I find the numerator?

Answer (score 2):

Neither (2) nor (3) are necessary. Note that, by definition, $E(T_1;T_1\lt T_2)$ is
$$
\int_0^\infty uf_{T_1}(u)\int_u^\infty f_{T_2}(v)\mathrm dv\mathrm du=\int_0^\infty \lambda_1u\mathrm e^{-\lambda_1 u}P(T_2\gt u)\mathrm du.
$$
Can you finish this?

Comment: Are you sure that is correct? When I integrate I get from your integral I get $\frac{\lambda_1}{(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)^2}$, but it is supposed to be $\frac{1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}$.

Comment: Yes I am sure... Note that, for every event A with positive probability and every integrable random variable T, E(T|A)=E(T;A)/P(A), which is all right since the answer indicates how to compute E(T;A) and you already know P(A).

Comment: Ok, I thought that ";" in you symbol meant the same as "|", but I now see that the answer then follows. Thanks.

Comment: BTW does that quantity E(T;A) have a meaning in itself? I have never seen it anywhere before, is there some interpretation of it?

Comment: This is the expectation of T restricted to the event A.