# Conditional expectation on exponential random

Tags: probability

I have a hard time solving this exercise :

Let $X_1 \sim \exp(\lambda_1)$ and $X_2 \sim \exp(\lambda_2)$. $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independant. We're seeking the following expectation : $\mathbb{E}[X_1 | X_1 > X_2]$.
But I don't know how to use the condition given on $X_1$ to find this expectation. Could someone help me (I don't want the answer, just hints)

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2034221/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/705108/321264

Answer (score 0):

First, relate $\mathbb{E}[X_1|X_1>X_2]$ to $\mathbb{E}[X_1 1\{X_1>X_2\}]$ and $\Pr(X_1>X_2)$. Second, use the law of iterated expectations to compute $\mathbb{E}[X_1 1\{X_1>X_2\}]$ and $\Pr(X_1>X_2)$.